# alternatives to roboform

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, passwords, software-rec, roboform

*Yes, I know there is already a few similar questions.*

Is there an alternative to RoboForm (which for some reason makes my FF very slow, because of some other extensions) which has the same way of working. What I mean, you click on ... and it opens a new tab with the page in question, and logs on to it (so no databases, and such ...). One other advantage would be if it kept passwords locally.

Basically, I'm looking for RoboForm other than RoboForm.

Anyone knows of any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No alternatives for Roboform yet but I think Firefox [Secure Login addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4429) is the best of Roboform alternatives...

Comment: Excellent add on - works flawlessly, and fast as hell ... +A

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a combo of [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) and Firefox's own [Form autocomplete](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Form+autocomplete?bl=n&s=forms) .

lastpass keeps all your passwords online and encrypted so only you can access them.
However, they're accessible anywhere in the world.

Comment: nope, sorry. i keep some important data (bank related) in it as well, and it's out of the question keeping those online (paranoic in me ;)

Comment: As one paranoiac to another: Only the encrypted data is kept on the website, so without the master password it's totally unreadable and useless. lastpass is really done correctly.

Comment: yeah, well ... all that is fine and all ... but until i get a signed statement from them, that they'll cover all expenses, i'm not putting anything more important than an email password online ... sorry. everything that is online stays online, and every encryption can be broken (and besides, i don't know enough about encr. to trust any). not gonna change my mind, sorry :) (here's +1 for trying though ;)

Answer (score 0):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) is very good:

> KeePass is a free open source password manager, which helps you to
>   manage your passwords in a secure way. You can put all your passwords
>   in one database, which is locked with one master key or a key file. So
>   you only have to remember one single master password or select the key
>   file to unlock the whole database. The databases are encrypted using
>   the best and most secure encryption algorithms currently known (AES
>   and Twofish).

[image]

Comment: does it offer an option to open a page and automatically logs you in ?

Comment: I honestly don't know.  Doesn't cost you anything to try it.  :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm asking because I used to use it, and it didn't back then (half a year ago), so I was wondering whether something major in that respect has changed in the more recent versions.

Comment: KeepPass has an autotype feature and you can open up links from KeePass in your default browser. Not sure if you can "link" those two steps though, but the autotype feature seems to be fairly configurable.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Opera](http://www.opera.com) and it's [Wand](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/2/) instead ;-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Those pretty much are the essential parts.